# Is it correct to say "…battle between x versus y"?

Tags: word-choice

Today I heard someone on television say this:

> In the battle between x *versus* y, x won.

Is this correct? In my opinion, this would sound better/be more correct:

> In the battle between x *and* y, x won.

What should have been said?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically speaking, the phrase should have been either

> The battle of X versus Y

or

> The battle between X and Y

I think it's more common to say "The battle of (placename)" or "the battle between x and y" instead of "the battle of x versus y", but I'll have to let someone else try to NGram that up.

However, I'm guessing that you were watching a show called "Man versus Food", and the host of the show isn't about to miss a chance to slip the name of the show in even if it makes the sentence sound a little funny.

Comment: That was the show. I suppose you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=battle+between+England+and%2Cbattle+of+England+versus%2Cbattle+between+England+versus&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) that show "battle between X and Y" is **much** more common than both "battle of X versus Y" and "battle between X versus Y", which you can't even see above the zero baseline:

[image: England]
[image: France]
[image: Athens]
[image: Alexander]

Comment: There's some awfully strange clustering in those graphs...